# str.slice is not a function

Tags: web3js, remix

I ran two command lines of web3 and it returned an error

```
> length ='0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002'
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002

> d0Slot = web3.utils.sha3(length, {encoding: 'hex'})

str.slice is not a function
```

Comment: From `web3.utils`, I conclude that you're using web3.js v1.x. If that is indeed the case, then use `soliditySha3` instead of `sha3`.

Comment: It works, thanks man! @goodvibration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning a comment into an answer:

From the "`web3.utils`" part in your code, I conclude that you are using web3.js v1.x.

If that is indeed the case, then use `web3.utils.soliditySha3` instead of `web3.utils.sha3`.